# Custom JQuery datepicker not returning selected date

Tags: jquery

I used datepicker plugin to build a custom selector that only gives me the option between the two semesters in a year. It has to be either January-June or July-December.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#semester" ).datepicker({
    stepMonths: 6,
    nextText: "Next semester",
    prevText: "Previous semester",
    monthNames: ["January - June", "", "", "", "", "", "July - December", "", "", "", "", ""]
});
$( "#semester" ).datepicker('setDate', new Date(2012,0,1));
});
</script>
```

and

```
<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Well, I can't post images yet, but it basically gives me a one-liner like "January-December ". Scrolling it to the right gives me "July-December 2012", and so on.

I call it using

```
<div id="semester" name="semester" class="date-picker"></div>
```

which inside a standard form with a standard Submit button.

Now, it looks just the way I want, since I don't want an `<input type="text">`but the problem is that this way the data isn't sent, according to print_r($_POST), but other elements in the form are. I'm obviously missing something here.

NOTE: I decided to use JQuery basically for design preference, since datepicker looks so neat. Although, I realize now that using JQuery for this was probably overkill, but since I've made it this far, I'd like to finish it.

Also, if someone has a better/less complicated and maybe even equally neat idea on how I can accomplish this, please tell me.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've found here in SO another topic in which the same problem I'm having is also present: [See the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8721023/1115775). Apparently, there's no way to select the date once I hide the days.
Perhaps the answer to this will include an event involving `setDate`? I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Div elements aren't included in form submissions, even with the name attribute. What you want to use is a hidden input, and have the value of this input change with your datepicker.

```
$( "#semester" ).datepicker({
    stepMonths: 6,
    nextText: "Next semester",
    prevText: "Previous semester",
    monthNames: ["January - June", "", "", "", "", "", "July - December", "", "", "", "", ""],
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month) {
        $('#semesterInput').val(month + ", " + year);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="semester" class="date-picker"> </div>
<input type="hidden" id="semesterInput" name="semester" />
```

Also, see the [jQuery Datepicker documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Comment: Your solution solved my problem only partially. You see, now when I `print_r($_POST)` I get an empty `semester` variable. I did some searching and my problem is pretty much the same as described in another topic. I've updated my answer with the SO link.

Comment: @Victor is your onSelect function firing? Add an alert or console.log inside the function to see if the function is being called when you select a date

Comment: @Victor Try the `onChangeMonthYear` event instead of `onSelect`

Comment: `onChangeMonthYear` now gives me `semester = <year>`, but the month isn't showing. Almost there :P

Comment: @Victor Cool, finding the proper event was the hard part. See the original answer above, it has been edited. The `onChangeMonthYear` event can take three arguments, the first two are the year and month.